# Parse a file using ANTLR4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, antlrworks

I have a Lexer and a Parser called y86 Lexer and Parser which work as far as I know. But I have a file with y86 commands and I want to parse them using Java. So far I have code as follows.

```
y86Lexer y86 = null;
CommonTokenStream tokenStream = null;
y86Parser y86p = null;

try
{
    y86 = new y86Lexer(CharStreams.fromFileName("C:\\Users\\saigbomian\\Documents"
            + "\\LearnANTLR\\src\\sum.ys"));
    tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(y86);
    y86p = new y86Parser(tokenStream);

}
catch (IOException e)
{
    log.error("Error occured while reading from file");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm not sure how to do the parsing. I have seen people use something like y86Parser.CompilationUnitContext but I can seem to find that class. I have tried printing from the Listeners antlr creates but I don't know how to trigger these listeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each rule `ruleName` in your grammar, the `y86Parser` class will contain a class named `RuleNameContext` and a method named `ruleName()`, which will parse the input according to that rule and return an instance of the `RuleNameContext` class containing the parse tree. You can then use listeners or visitors to walk that parse tree.

So if you don't have a `compilationUnit` method or a `CompilationUnitContext` class, your grammar probably just doesn't have a rule named `compilationUnit`. Instead you should pick a rule that you do have and call the method corresponding to that rule.

Comment: Thank you. That works. But when I try using the walker it gets only the first command. Any idea why that might be? @sepp2k

Comment: @PhoenixKing My first guesses would be that you're invoking a rule that only matches a single command or that you're invoking a rule that could match multiple commands, but doesn't because of a parse error that goes otherwise unnoticed because you didn't anchor your rule to `EOF`. Beyond that I'd have to see your code (or rather an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it).

Comment: You're probably right. I am invoking one rule called validY86 which is basically all of the rules as seen in this [grammar file](https://codeshare.io/all9eB). I'm not sure how to make it go through the entire file.

Comment: @PhoenixKing Something like `program : validY86+ EOF;`. Use `*` instead of `+` if you want to allow empty files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 2 days in a row you've helped me understand ANTLR4